# Execute PHP Echo inside input tag (text field)

Tags: php, html

I'm using a function inside a php script to return a text field containing a value. This value is retrieved from a variable. How can I make this possible?

This is the code that I tried to use but it didn't work.

```
function display_name()
{   
    return '<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" value=" '. $current_user->display_name .'" name="CreatedBy" style="width:100%">';
}
```

Comment: can you show me where you want to display or echo this return value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By handing the function the variable as a parameter.

```
function display_name($current_user)
{   
    return '<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" value=" '. $current_user->display_name .'" name="CreatedBy" style="width:100%">';
}
```

then calling it like

```
display_name($current_user);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see absolutely no point in having such a function.
It will make your code bloated and hard to maintain.

Why not just have this piece of HTML just along other HTML codes in the *template*?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" value="<?=$current_user->display_name?>" name="CreatedBy" style="width:100%">
```

or at least make it more generalized, to make it call like this

```
html_input("text",'CreatedBy',$current_user->display_name,
           array("maxlength=>"50",readonly=>"readonly",style=>"width:100%"));
```

to use such a function for the every input on the site.